# A user is able to login into my site despite not having existed as a user in my membership table - why is this?

Tags: php, codeigniter

If a user does not exist its supposed to throw back an error on the login screen but the user is then brought to the home page as if they have previously registered in my sign controller. The login controller - validate credentials function - and my model - function can_log_in() -   will illustrate the error its supposed to bounce back

model:

```
  class Membership extends CI_Model
{
function Membership()
{
    parent::__construct();
}


public function can_log_in()
{
    $this->db->select('*')->from('membership');
    $this->db->where('username', $this->input->post ('username'));
    $this->db->where('password', md5($this->input->post ('password')));

    $query = $this->db->get('membership');
    if ($query->num_rows() == 1)
    {
        return true;
    }

    else{

        return false;

    }

}
```

login controller:

```
 class Login extends CI_Controller 
 {

   function Login()
    {
     parent::__construct();

      $this->load->model('membership');
    }


    function loguserin()

    {

$this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));

$this->load->library('form_validation');

$this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'required|min_length[5]|max_length[12]|trim');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required|md5|trim');


$username = $this->input->post('username');
$password = $this->input->post('password');
      if ($this->form_validation->run()==TRUE)
     {
          $this->load->model('membership');
           if($this->membership->can_log_in($this->input->post('username'),$this->input->post('password'))
       { // this is unepected despite a new if statement called
        $this->session->set_userdata('status', 'OK');
        $this->session->set_userdata('username', $username);  
        redirect('home');
        } else //this else is unexpected
          {
       $this->session->set_userdata('status', 'NOT_OK');

      $this->session->set_flashdata('Incorrect username/password');
       $this->index();
      }
    } else {
   $this->index; 

   }

  }







        function logout()
      {
$this->session->sess_destroy();
redirect ('start');
       }


      function index()
      {
      $this->load->view('shared/header');
       $this->load->view('account/logintitle');
      $this->load->view('account/loginview');
        $this->load->view('shared/footer');
       }
      }
```

Once again thanks :) its just that the user if not already in the table should not be able to sign into the home page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your logic is all over the place and you're misunderstanding the concept of form validation. Form validation validates form input that's it, it does not validate credentials. The validate_credentials function you have is sort of pointless to be honest since you can't call the form validation error from outside the run function. So you may as well just make that go away entirely.

First, the initial call after form_validation should be like this:

```
if ($this->form_validation->run()==TRUE)
{
    $this->load->model('membership');
    if($this->membership->can_log_in($this->input->post('username'),$this->input->post('password')))
    {
    $this->session->set_userdata('status', 'OK');
    $this->session->set_userdata('username', $username);  
    redirect('home');
    } else {
    $this->session->set_userdata('status', 'NOT_OK');// you'll need to do something
   // here to tell them their credentials are wrong as I said this won't work through
   // the form validation, perhaps look into using $this->session->set_flashdata()
    $this->index();
    }
} else {
$this->index; //reload the index to display the validation errors
```

Okay that takes care of sending the data to the login function, now the function actually needs to receive data, and since it is NOT the first page sent the data the post string will be empty, that is why I passed the data in the function above. The only part of the model that should need to change is the following:

```
public function can_log_in($username,$password)
{
$this->db->select('*')->from('membership');
$this->db->where('username', $username);
$this->db->where('password', md5($password));
```

Comment: Are u sure an if else statement within an if else statement is allowed?

Comment: Thanks for that concise response. I have tried the following :pls see the above amendment

Comment: I missed a closing bracket on this line:  if($this->membership->can_log_in($this->input->post('username'),$this->input->post('password')))  If you get unexpected errors always check that all your braces close in the previous statements and that you end the lines with semi colons, it's rarely what it calls the error and is almost always before that. Keep in mind you're still going to need to make the change to your model too for it to work at all.

Answer (score 0):

try replacing

```
if ($this->form_validation->run())
```

with

```
if ($this->form_validation->run() && validate_credentials())
```